# Are there any free static analysis tools for C# / .NET code

Tags: source-code, code-review, opensource

A client recently asked me to perform a code review on C# code. As an independent contractor I was wondering what are the automated solutions out there where I would not have to break the bank to carry out similar assignments.

So far I have come across the O2 Platform but the documentation is all over the place. Microsoft's FxCop is another tool I found but their reports are horrible and I'd like something that would give me a report which I could use to further carry out a manual inspection without having to pull out my hair trying to read output.

What recommendations do you have for carrying out a code review in terms of a quality scan, free / relatively low pricing for an independent contractor and good reporting?

Comment: This question might end up as a 'list', which tends not to do well on IS.SE. I will point you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#.NET

Comment: The challenge is finding a SAST tool. In terms of general code review, I saw the Wikipedia list. One article I found was at: http://www.securityninja.co.uk/application-security/can-you-implement-static-analysis-without-breaking-the-bank/  but haven't found anything similar for C#. If there's a comparison between different SAST tools in terms of costs and quality especially for a small business or independent consultant, that would be great.

Comment: I know it is an outdated question, but can you tell me if Static Application Security Testing(SAST) is same as Source Code analysis tool? Like the ones I am seeing here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools Are they just same thing but different names?

Answer (score 7):

<s>Roslyn Security Guard is now available and is free. https://dotnet-security-guard.github.io/</s>

Update: This project is no longer maintained and has been forked here and improved here: https://github.com/security-code-scan/security-code-scan.

By the way, be sure to enable it for the full codebase by choosing `Tools > Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> "Enable full solution analysis"`.

Comment: I've tried this myself and it looks promising.

Answer (score 5):

SAST tools in general tend to be pretty expensive for on-site hosted solutions and for c# I'm not aware of many good free tools

One option you could look at is the on-demand style scanning that several of the tool vendors do, which is likely to be cheaper if you're doing a smaller number of scans and also is something you might be able to factor into the cost of your assessments.

Some options

- [Checkmarx](http://www.checkmarx.com/solutions-2/cxcloud-on-demand/)
- [Fortify](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1337215)
- [Veracode](http://www.veracode.com/products/static) (NB their approach is different in that it looks at the binary rather than source)

Comment: Have a look to sonarqube.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CAT.NET from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19968

Its a snapin for visual studio that does static analysis on a number of different languages.

Comment: CAT.NET is interesting, but unfortunately it's not (AFAIK) maintained and there haven't been any updates in the last couple of years.

Comment: That link is now dead